# How to calculate the tensor of inertia in this problem?

Tags: tensor-calculus, rigid-body-dynamics, inertia, solid-mechanics

I have the following geometry for my problem:

[image]

I'm asked to calculate the tensor of Inertia:

$\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{I}_{O}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}{I_{11}} & {-P_{12}} & {-P_{13}} \\ {-P_{21}} & {I_{22}} & {-P_{23}} \\ {-P_{31}} & {-P_{21}} & {I_{33}}\end{array}\right]$

For any component I know is calculated as:

$I_{i j}=\int d m \cdot\left(r^{2} \delta_{i j}-x_{i} \cdot x_{j}\right)$

So, for example, if I choose to calculate the first component of that tensor, it will be this integral:

$I_{11}=\int dm\cdot (r^2-x_1^2)=\int dm\cdot (x_2^2+x_3^2)$

For linear geometries, we know that:

$dm=\lambda\cdot dl=\frac{M}{L}\cdot dl$

How do I solve the integrals correctly, for components $I_{11}$,$I_{22}$ and $I_{33}$? I know the final solution is:

$\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{I}_{O}=\frac{ML^2}{2}\cdot \left[\begin{array}{ccc}{1} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {2}\end{array}\right]$

Please help, I'm really struggling to figure this out :(

Comment: Have you considered that $dl$ might be something like $dx_1+dx_2+dx_3$ (looks like three solid lines in image)?

Comment: @Emil yes there are three solid lines, but how can I apply that to the integral?

Comment: You need to connect the integrand with the differential, I made a suggestion on how to do that. The integral itself is just a polynomial, the first kind of integral you learn in school... My suggestion would only be valid at point O, in other places the differential is zero or just one of them not the sum. (Try to create a formula for $m$ and take the differential of it)